# Большая ложь о приоритетах операторов в Javascript. Или и так сойдет?

Tags: javascript, order, expressions

Во всех учебниках и уроках что я читал, всегда пишут что первым выполнится тот оператор в выражении, у которого больше приоритет. И вроде бы это логично. Но давайте спросим у самого языка. Вот вам два примера:

```js
var a = 10;
a = a + (a = 5);
console.log(a);
```

```js
var a = 10;
a = a++ + (a + 5);
console.log(a);
```

В первом и втором примере левая часть вычисляется до скобок, хотя у скобок наивысший приоритет. Я уже понял алгоритм, для меня это не проблема. Но!!! Почему этого нет ни в одном учебнике? Что это и почему так? Канешно врядли кто-то знает ответ, просто так есть и надо мирится.

Comment: А потому, что вы неправильно понимаете разбор выражения (expression). Выражения разбираются слева-направо, у каждого оператора есть левая и правая часть, которые тоже могут быть выражениями (и достаточно сложными). К примеру в сложении expression + expression, где в качестве expression может быть все, что угодно, сначала выполнится левое, потом правое выражение.

Comment: А сам приоритет нужен для того, чтобы у вас не получилась каша при разборе: `10 * 2 + 3` и `3 + 10 * 2` всегда дадут одно и то же. За счет того, что у сложения приоритет ниже, он не попадает в умножение и не получается подобного казуса `expr(10) * expr(2 + 3)` т.к. умножение не подхватывает в правый expression знак сложения `expr(10) * expr(2) + 3`, а вот степень подхватит: `expr(10) * expr(2 ** 3)`.

Comment: Это да, верно. Хотелось что бы еще чтоб об этом писали в учебниках. Ведь по сути алгоритм вычисления немного сложнее чем пишут. Сначала ищется оператор с самым низким приоритетом, и вычисляется его левая часть. Даже если в правой части операторы с приоритетом "царь во дворца". Но об этом никто не пишет. Какой-то заговор и я его раскрыл!! За мою голову назначат награду - 12 ядерный райзен и трусы с ргб подсветкой!!

Answer (score 0):

Могу привести даже более пугающий пример, надеюсь он прояснит ситуацию :)

```js
var obj = {
  get A()
  {
     console.log('A!');
     return 5;
  },
  get B()
  {
     console.log('B!');
     return 2;
  }
}
var result = obj.A + obj.B * 2;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Т.е. все куски операций разбиваются на функции, которые возвращают значение? А где-то об этом написано?

Comment: а где он должен быть пугающим? я тоже анимешник, но не настолько пугливый